# content behind fixed flex navbar instead of below

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I created a simple navbar and arranged its children with flex box. The position of the navbar is fixed. But the container (div) after the navbar start from the beginning of the page instead of after the navbar, I believe its being ignored cause its position property is fixed.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 40px;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar>.social-icons {}

.logo {
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.icon:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.block:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: purple;
}

.block:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.email-signup {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkblue
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/iconmonstr-paper-plane-1.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="social-icons">
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-facebook-4.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-instagram-1.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-twitter-4.svg" alt=""></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="email-signup"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="social-icons">
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-facebook-4.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-instagram-1.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-twitter-4.svg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried adding padding-top: 40px; to body but this show up as a space above the navbar

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 40px;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar>.social-icons {}

.logo {
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.icon:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.block:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: purple;
}

.block:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.email-signup {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkblue
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/iconmonstr-paper-plane-1.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="social-icons">
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-facebook-4.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-instagram-1.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-twitter-4.svg" alt=""></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="email-signup"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="social-icons">
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-facebook-4.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-instagram-1.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-twitter-4.svg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Assuming I'm reading this right, you could try adding `padding-top: 40px` to the `.blocks` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-top: 40px` to your `.blocks` class. That will keep the navbar fixed to the top and shift your blocks down.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.navbar {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 40px;
}

.social-icons {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar>.social-icons {}

.logo {
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.icon:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.block:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: purple;
}

.block:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.email-signup {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkblue
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/iconmonstr-paper-plane-1.svg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="social-icons">
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-facebook-4.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-instagram-1.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-twitter-4.svg" alt=""></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <div class="block">Test Content</div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="email-signup"></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="social-icons">
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-facebook-4.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-instagram-1.svg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="icon"><img src="images/iconmonstr-twitter-4.svg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```